JWT Not Expiring on React
I am trying to expiring jwt token. Code is below;
const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: 5 });

or
const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: "5s" });

It's not working on frontend. I think local storage isn't removing expired token but that's not the if the token is expired then it shouldn't allow route to access but still I can access all the routes that are protected on the front end. Should I make some logic on the client side to check the expiry of the token?
I have also tried jwt_decode on React, but it's giving me anonymous errors even chatGPT failed to solve it.

This question is similar to: How to detect jwt token expire on React. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Who are you expecting to "remove" the token?

but still I am able access to access all the route that are make protected on the frontend. What conditions are you using to protect the routes? and More over localstorage wont remove the expired tokens,we should validate the token expiry and generate a new one

what are "anonymous errors"?

I think you have not set up the protected routes correctly, here's one way of how to do it correctly:
In your App.jsx,
make this function:
export const isAuthenticated = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
  if (!token) {
    return false;
  }

  try {
    const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
    const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000; // Convert to seconds

    // Check if the token is expired
    if (decodedToken.exp < currentTime) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    localStorage.clear();
    console.log("User logged out!");
    return false;
  }
};

and declare a protected route as:
const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
  return isAuthenticated() ? children : <Navigate to="/login/page" />;
};

This is how you should make declare protected routes in your code:
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  // User Routes
  {
    path: "/users/signup",
    element: <SignUp />,
  },
  {
    path: "/users/login",
    element: <LogIn />,
  },

  // Protected Routes
  {
    path: "/",
    element: (
      <PrivateRoute>
        <ProtectedLayout />
      </PrivateRoute>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        path: "/users/update_profile",//replace with the route you want to make protected

        element: (
          <PrivateRoute>
            <UpdateProfile /> //Replace with the component you want to render
          </PrivateRoute>
        ),
      },
      
    ],
  },
]);

here are some necessary imports for the above code to work:
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Navigate,
} from "react-router-dom";


Thank you for your response. But I had installed jwt-decode previously but it always giving me this error I don't know why.
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/jwt-decode.js?v=4a11fb61' does not provide an export named 'default' (at protectedRoute.jsx:2:8)

@Yousuf are you importing jwt-decode in this way?
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";
